# Short-cut for computing some large number N (mod 3)

Tags: arithmetic

Is it OK to assert that a number (mod 3) is the sum of each of its digit (mod 3), i.e., for an n-digit number represented by
a1a2a3...an (mod 3) = a1 (mod 3) + a2 (mod 3) + a3 (mod 3) + ... + an( mod 3) ?

Comment: That's perfectly correct. It's also true mod $9$. This is because $10\equiv 1\mod3$ (resp. $9$).

Comment: Good ! Then can we further simplify it by saying : "a number (mod 3) is its digital root (mod 3)" ?

Comment: ??? I have not the least idea of what  a ‘digital root’ is, so I couldn't tell you.

Comment: Digital root of a number N is the sum of its digits iterated until a single digit is obtained and is in fact equal to N (mod 9). For instance, digital root of 58635967351 is digital root of (5 + 8 + 6 + 3 + 5 + 9 + 6 + 7 + 3 + 5 + 1 =  58) is the digital root of (5 + 8 = 13) is equal to 1 + 3 = 4. This is most easily computed by casting out 9's,  then sum of digits that add up to 9"s.

Comment: Didn't know this name…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite, but you're close.  Assuming you mean the decimal digits, then what you have is that

$$d_nd_{n-1}\dots d_1d_0\equiv (d_n\hspace{-1em}\mod 3+d_{n-1}\hspace{-1em}\mod 3+\dots+d_0\hspace{-1em}\mod 3)\pmod 3$$

The reason that you can't just say that the number mod $3$ "is" the sum of all of its digits (with each digit taken mod $3$) is that that value might be too large; even though they're in the same equivalence class, when we talk about $n\mod 3$ we usually mean the smallest member of that equivalence class; in other words, the remainder when $n$ is divided by $3$.  So, for instance, $111111\mod 3$ 'is' $0$, since it's divisible by $3$ - but $1+1+1+1+1+1$ is $6$.  But of course $0\equiv 6\pmod 3$, so they *are* in the same residue class.

The reason that this is so, incidentally, is because $10\equiv 1\pmod 3$, so (because modularity 'respects' multiplication), $10^n\equiv 1\pmod 3$ for all $n$; and since $d_nd_{n-1}\ldots d_1d_0$ is shorthand notation for $d_n\times 10^n+d_{n-1}\times 10^{n-1}+\ldots$, we can write
$$\begin{align}
d_nd_{n-1}\ldots d_0 &= d_n\times 10^n+d_{n-1}\times 10^{n-1}+\dots\\
&\equiv d_n\hspace{-1em}\mod 3\times 10^n\hspace{-1em}\mod 3+d_{n-1}\hspace{-1em}\mod 3\times 10^{n-1}\hspace{-1em}\mod 3+\dots \\
&\equiv d_n\hspace{-1em}\mod 3\times 1+d_{n-1}\hspace{-1em}\mod 3\times 1+\dots\\
&\equiv (d_n\hspace{-1em}\mod 3+d_{n-1}\hspace{-1em}\mod 3+\dots+d_0\hspace{-1em}\mod 3) \pmod 3
\end{align}$$

Comment: Application : Given the largest product of numbers that add up to N is 3^(N/3) or 4*3^{(N - 4)/3} or 2*3^{(N - 2)/3} according as to whether N (mod 3) is 0, 1 or 2. Thus, for N = 31122016 working (mod 3) we have N ≡ 1, so that maximum product of numbers that add up to 31122016 is 4*3^10374004.

Comment: Further to the previous comment, the quotient [31122016/3] can be obtained without long division as [(3 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 0 + 1 + 6)/3] + 3(3112201 + 311220 + 31122 + 3112 + 311 + 31 + 3) = 5 + 3×3458000 = 10374005.